# Map<K, Object> => Map<K, String>

Tags: java

Given a `Map<K, Object>`, I'm returning `Map<K, String>` or throwing an Exception for at least one non-String value.

```
     private static <K> Map<K, String> validate(final Map<K, Object> map) 
                        throws NonStringValueException {
    final List<Object> invalidValues = new ArrayList<Object>();
    final Map<K, String> result = new HashMap<K, String>();

    for(Map.Entry<K, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if(!(entry.getValue() instanceof String)) {
            invalidValues.add(entry.getValue());
        }
        else {
            result.put(entry.getKey(), (String) entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    if(!invalidValues.isEmpty()) {
        throw new NonStringValueException("Invalid Values: 
            must be `String` type: " + invalidValues);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Besides using `instanceOf` and then casting, is there a better way to write this method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some simple things first - there's no need to repeat the generic type of variables on the right-hand-side of a new assignment. Java 7 introduced the "diamond operator" `<>` and the generic type is inferred. So, lines like:

> ```
> final List<Object> invalidValues = new ArrayList<Object>();
> final Map<K, String> result = new HashMap<K, String>();
> ```

can be just:

```
final List<Object> invalidValues = new ArrayList<>();
final Map<K, String> result = new HashMap<>();
```

Your use of the static method and generic type `<K>` is good. I like how you have made the variables final in the method too. Additionally, your use of the for-each loop on the Map's entries is also good.

A comment on your generics, your input map should be `Map<K, ?>` instead of `Map<K, Object>` .... the `?` allows more flexibility.

Java introduced a couple of helper methods on `Class` a while back, and I think you could use these to make this method even more generic.... why force it to only be a String?

Consider the following two methods:

```
private static <K, V> Map<K, V> validate(Class<V> coerce, final Map<K, ?> map) 
        throws IllegalArgumentException {
    final List<Object> invalidValues = new ArrayList<>();
    final Map<K, V> result = new HashMap<>();

    for(Map.Entry<K, ?> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if(coerce.isInstance(entry.getValue())) {
            result.put(entry.getKey(), coerce.cast(entry.getValue()));
        } else {
            invalidValues.add(entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    if(!invalidValues.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Values: must be `" + coerce.getName() +  "` type: " + invalidValues);
    }

    return result;
}

public static <K> Map<K, String> validate(Map<K, ?> map) {
    return validate(String.class, map);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful answer - I liked the generic `Class<V>` that you taught me. Lastly, what are your thoughts about using a checked exception instead - to let the compiler help us out more?

Comment: The checked exception is very much dependent on your context. I am not sure whether it is "right", but I seldom create custom exceptions any more, and rely on native exceptions. Further, I am using unchecked more often too (like `IllegalArgumentException`) because it helps when using Java 8 streams.

Comment: `allows more flexibility`. And that's because of what Joshua Bloch says in Item 23 of Effective Java: `you can't put any element (other than null) into a Collection<?>.`? That's the reason for using `?` over `Object` in your answer?

Comment: @KevinMeredith - it's a little complicated, but the `<?>` will accept maps of any generic type, like String, Integer, etc... whereas `<Object>` will take only `Object`.... see this code, and try to compile it: http://pastebin.com/Ypj3exaP